# What would be the regular expression for this pattern in Python3?

Tags: regex, string, python-3.x

```
s = "ababa"
```

I used the following Regex:

```
match = re.search(r'(ab|ba)+', s)
```

But the output I got was:

```
abab
```

While I want it to be (It should detect alternate characters):

```
ababa
```

Forgive me if it looks silly, but I am a regex noob.

Comment: try (ab)*a it might work for you

Comment: You cannot expect that regex to match what you state you need, because the pattern you have does not contain lookarounds that are crucial when overlapping matches are expected. Try [`(a(?=b|$)|b(?=a|$))+`](https://regex101.com/r/wLU9YM/1), but I doubt it will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

`r'(a(ba)*b?|b(ab)*a?)'`

This will match patterns that start with either a or b, and with any amount of alternations between the two thereafter.

Comment: Just an observation, this regex won't do what you think. Your regex will match `a` or `b` by themselves separately. Also it will not continue the match but stop at this boundary `ababa`abab

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for (general way):

```
((.)(?!\2).)(?:\1+\2?|\2)
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/ItjRHM/1)

That means:

```
(                # capture group 1: group of two different characters
    (.)          # capture group 2: first character
    (?!\2).      # a character that isn't the same of the character in group 2 
)                # close capture group 1
(?:              # two possibilities:
    \1+\2?       # repeat the group 1 (at least once) with an optional first character at the end
  |              # OR
    \2           # the first character
)
```

With fixed characters (`a` and `b`):

```
a(?:ba)*b?|b(?:ab)*a?
```

or

```
a(?:ba)+b?|b(?:ab)+a?
```

*(for at least three characters.)*

Comment: Probably could make that last part optional so it can match ab or ba alone `((.)(?!\2)(.))(?:\1+\2?|\2)?` Still, all these regexs are discontinuous at `ab`ba or `ba`ab boundary's.

Answer (score 0):

My approach:

```
(.)(.)(?:\1\2)+\1?
```

*A followed by B, followed by one or more A-then-B and possibly another A.*

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zndmuT/1)